# How to show multiple subcategories in URL

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Currently I have `/%category%/%postname%/` in permalinks, which works for items in one category, but it doesn't work for nested categories, eg:

```
 Electronics > Computers > Lenovo > postname
```

I want the URL to be `www.website.com/electronics/computers/lenovo/postname`

Answer (score 0):

Create nested categories and select ONLY the final category in the post edit screen: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried that and made sure they only have one category selected, but for some reason it keeps saying page not found whenever I assign something to a sub category. Even if I put post name as default. The sub categories also show as not found. When I click on the root category it shows all items that are supposed to be in the subcategories, but when you click any item you get 404. Please see rpgsoog.com to see what I mean.

Comment: Go to the permalinks page in the admin section and just click on "Save" without changing anything. This will refresh all of the htaccess rules. See if that fixes it.